# string.Format(…, double) followed by double.Parse using same NumberFormatInfo results in FormatException. Why?

Tags: c#, string, double, string-parsing, string.format

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo()
{
    CurrencySymbol = "$$s. ",
    CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".",
    CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",",
    NegativeSign = "-",
    CurrencyNegativePattern = 2
};

double amount = double.Parse("$$s. 1.123,00", nfi);
```

The last line throws a `FormatException`, and I don't know why. The string I'm trying to parse actually comes from this:

```
String.Format(nfi, "{0:C}", 1123.00)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not telling it that it *should* accept a currency value. To do that, you need to call an overload which accepts a `NumberStyles` value, and include `NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol`. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo()
        {
            CurrencySymbol = "$$s. ",
            CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".",
            CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",",
            NegativeSign = "-",
            CurrencyNegativePattern = 2
        };

        double d = double.Parse("$$s. 1.123,00",
            NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol,
            nfi);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

Note that currency values are generally better represented as `decimal` than `double` though.